# AngularJS new value does not arrive in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I have the following directive riding a modal. `File: login.component.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myapp');

    app.directive('loginComponent', ['loginService', function(loginService){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: 'homeCrotroller',
            link: function ($scope) {
                $scope.submit = function() {
                    $scope.login();
                    $("#modal-login").modal('hide');
                };

                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $scope.loggingIn = false;
                    $("#modal-login").modal('hide');
                };

                $scope.$watch('loggingIn', function() {                    
                    if ($scope.loggingIn) {
                        $("#modal-login").modal('show');
                    };
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

})();
```

And the next controller. `File: home.controller.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myapp');

    app.controller('homeCrotroller', ['$scope', function($scope){

        $scope.loggedIn = false;
        $scope.loggingIn = false;

        $scope.showLogin = function () {
            $scope.loggingIn = true;
        };

        $scope.logout = function () {
            $scope.user = null;
            $scope.loggedIn = false;
        };

        $scope.login = function () {
            $scope.loggingIn = false;
            $scope.loggedIn = true;
        };

    }]);

})();
```

And in my view I call `showLogin()`

```
<a class="login" id="btn-login" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="showLogin()" title="Entrar">Entrar</a>
```

This function changes the value of `$scope.logging` In to `true`, only this value is not reaching policy. Only reaches the first status (loading screen) that is `false`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code other than you misspelled `homeCrotroller` twice. Are you sure you are pulling in both `.js` files in your `index.html`?

Comment: Are you using `<load-component></load-component>` in a html file?

Comment: Yes, I'm use `<load-component></load-component>`. I'm generating the javascript  .min with Grunt, grunt-ngannotate, grunt-contrib-concat and uglify

Comment: When I changed the value of variable $scope.loggingIn for true and recharge the screen gonna work but with click alternating the value not working.